# How Read .lic file from phone memory

Tags: android

i have problem how read license file from phone memory.I'm trying this code but not found any data .

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("License.lic");
if (is == null)
    throw new IOException("cannot find resource: "+resourcePath);


System.out.println( getBytesFromInputStream(is));
```

Comment: What u mean `Read license file from phone memory` ? where u have added `License.lic` in project?

Comment: How you have added `License.lic` in `phone memory` ?

Answer (score 0):

**This will work Definitely to read file from Internal storage**.

```
try {
FileReader fr = new FileReader(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/foldernm/file.txt");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fr);
String line;
         while((line=reader.readLine())!=null) {
              Toast.makeText(getApplication(),line+"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
      }catch(IOException ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
  }
```